# Is Mn(C₂H₃O₂)₂ soluble in water?

Tags: solubility

Also, can you explain why, as in which solubility rules apply in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. This looks like a homework level question of the type. Help us help you by letting us know what you have tried or where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes it is**. But have no idea on its *$\ce{Ksp}$* or *$\ce{g/L}$* value! If I'm not wrong, it's [Manganese(II) acetate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganese%28II%29_acetate).

'Which rule applies' is the following :

**`All nitrates, acetates and perchlorates are soluble in water.`**

Possibility of **H**-bonding adds to acetates' solubility in water.  Have a look at the first few lines of this [abstract](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001JChEd..78..111V), it's quite explanatory.  However, few acetates like those of *$\ce{Ag}$*, *$\ce{Hg}$* or  **$\ce{Pb}$** are slightly soluble.